# JSON : what is the java Map equivalent in c#

Tags: c#, java, json, serialization, dictionary

I am facing the problem that using JSON to pass an object to C# and C# pass a string back to Java and then java deserialize it to a Map
BTW, the .net version is 3.5

Here is the problem

the java map JSON string is in this format:

```
{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
```

but in C#, the dictionary is seralized to

```
[{"Key":"key1","Value":"value1"},{"Key":"key2","Value":"value2"}]
```

I just want find a way to do this:

1. for java Map JSON format, C# could deseralize it
2. for C#, find a way to seralize it to a java understandable format

Thanks

Comment: Which serializer are you using? JavaScriptSerializer or DataContractJsonSerializer? (or a third-party serializer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) instead of [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx):

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "key1", "value1" },
    { "key2", "value2" }
};
var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string json = jss.Serialize(dict); // {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
```

Answer (score -1):

I wrote an extension method for Dictionary to serialize it to JSON:

```
public static string SerializeToJson(this IDictionary<string, object> dict)
{
  var sb = new StringBuilder();

  sb.Append("{");

  foreach (string key in dict.Keys)
  {
    sb.AppendFormat("\"{0}\": \"{1}\"", key, dict[key]);
    sb.Append(key != dict.Keys.Last() ? ", " : String.Empty);
  }

  sb.Append("}");

  return sb.ToString();
}
```

So you can write:

```
var jsonString = myDict.SerializeToJson();
```

Comment: What if `dict[key]` contains `"`? Or worse something like `haha","key666":"value666`