# Extracting part of JSON response

Tags: c#, json

I am new in programming. I am currently working on a map function which requires me to get directions between current location and the final location, but I do not know how to extract the text from the JSON RESPONSE.

This JSON response is generated from the api.

This is only a part of the JSON response.

```
{
      "attributes" : {
        "length" : 0.094387438, 
        "time" : 0.2831, 
        "text" : "Go west on _________", 
        "ETA" : 1365037200000, 
        "maneuverType" : "esriDMTStraight"
      }, 
      "compressedGeometry" : "+1+t1b+170r-2f-a-e-2"
    }
```

I wish to extract the "text" in the codes I show to display it on a listbox.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to deserialize your JSON to a C# class, You can use [Newtonsoft JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) Converters. To create a class that can hold your JSON object, you can copy your sample json and paste it in http://json2csharp.com/ that will give you the `RootObject` class, from there you can access the `text`, which would be available under property named `text`.

For the above sampel JSON you would get a class like:

```
public class Attributes
{
    public double length { get; set; }
    public double time { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public long ETA { get; set; }
    public string maneuverType { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Attributes attributes { get; set; }
    public string compressedGeometry { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it helps a lot, but how do I call the "text" property and display it in a list box? I'm poor in programming

Answer (score 0):

refer this links.hope it will helps u to sortout ur issue

[refer link 01](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136250/json-what-is-the-java-map-equivalent-in-c-sharp)

[refer link 02](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh674188.aspx)